# How to install stockfish on ubuntu?

Tags: engines, stockfish

Is there an easy guide how to install [stockfish](http://stockfishchess.org/) on ubuntu?

From the main site I can not find any information and [github repository](https://github.com/mcostalba/Stockfish) does not provide many details.

I would really appreciate if someone who already installed and started to run it would share the steps.

Comment: https://chess.stackexchange.com/a/19444/18370 is the best answer so far

Comment: `chs` is a convenient CLI UI for Stockfish: https://github.com/nickzuber/chs for it. Related for CLI UIs: https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/1600/chess-program-for-linux-unix-console GNOME Chess is a more user friendly GUI UI: https://github.com/flathub/org.gnome.Chess/issues/13

Answer (score 30):

Just for completeness, I would like to add more explicit instructions for using stockfish in Scid, because sometimes it is a little confusing how to get stockfish to function in an actual chess program.

```
sudo apt-get install scid
sudo apt-get install stockfish
```

Load Scid
In Scid Click:

```
Tools -> Analysis Engine (click twice) -> New
    Set Name to ‘stockfish’
    Command is /usr/games/stockfish (use ‘which stockfish’ if not)
    Directory : Click the ~/.scid button
    Hit OK and select the stockfish engine
```

Hopefully this is straightforward enough that anybody could replicate it.

Comment: This installs an old copy of Stockfish.

Comment: Is studo a typo for sudo?

Comment: Full path to `stockfish` executable is not required tested as of scid 4.7.4, just `stockfish` works.

Answer (score 7):

As probably you already know Stockfish is "only" a chess engine. It means it's "only" the part of the program that makes the thinking, and it has no interface at all.

I haven't used Ubuntu for a while, but AFAIK Stockfish is available on its repositories, so you should be able to install it just by:
$ sudo apt-get install stockfish

If for whatever reason you need/want to install Stockfish from the sources, once you've downloaded the code from the github repo, you just need a C++ compiler (v.g. g++) and from the "src" folder enter the command:
$ make build ARCH=x86-64    (This is for 64-bit systems)
$ make build ARCH=x86-32    (This is for 32-bit systems)

In order to be able to play against Stockfis you need a chess GUI, for example Arena (only windows version, so you need wine in order to make it work) and ScidVsPC are vey popular:
http://scidvspc.sourceforge.net/
http://www.playwitharena.com/

Once you've installed a GUI and the Stockfish engine, you just have to add the Stockfish engine to the GUI in order to be able to play against it.

Comment: Stockfish is on Ubuntu repositories and SCID is also available. SCIDvsPC isn't

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend that you download the engine from https://stockfishchess.org/.

Unzip the zip file and go into the src folder.

```
unzip stockfish-7-linux.zip
cd stockfish-7-linux/src
```

Call the make script i.e.

```
make build ARCH=x86-64
```

Answer (score 5):

Don't use apt-get because it doesn't give the latest Stockfish version. Do this:

```
wget https://stockfishchess.org/files/stockfish-10-linux.zip
unzip stockfish-10-linux.zip
chmod +x stockfish-10-linux/Linux/stockfish_10_x64
./stockfish-10-linux/Linux/stockfish_10_x64
```

Comment: Is this accurate? `apt show stockfish` returns `Version: 8-3` on my machine (Ubuntu 17.04, so not even the latest Ubuntu).

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: This is the right answer as of 2023 because the `apt install stockfish` will not install the latest.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you simply use this command in your Terminal:

> sudo apt-get install stockfish

Answer (score 3):

The package is referenced at http://packages.debian.org/sid/i386/stockfish/download which can be installed with aptitude or synaptic.

Try this [Link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1531296) for more info

Comment: Needs to be update though: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/stockfish/+bugs