# Strong chess program for GNU/Linux with a command line interface?

Tags: engines, software

I'm looking for a **strong** chess program for GNU/Linux with a command line interface, or one that I can alter to make it suit my needs

After a quick search, I found the question [Chess program for Linux/Unix console](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/1600/chess-program-for-linux-unix-console), which gives some programs that are either too slow or too weak (with no command line though, it was on terminal, but that is easily manageable).

Comment: So the main differences between your question and the other question is that you are looking for *strong* programs. Are there any other differences? (E.g. screen reader accessibility?)

Comment: Your question makes no sense. Stockfish is part of the answer. You can't get better than that.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote about **Stockfish** in the link you had. I don't see there is any engine better than that.

Comment: OP may not understand the textual interface there. It's not "command line" as in "shell command line", it's the UCI interface. Free UCI documentation available for download at shredder.com I believe.